# E: Package 'postgresql-9.6' has no installation candidate

Tags: postgresql, linux-mint

Linux Mint 20.2

I want to install PostgreSQL 9.6.

Here my steps:

- sudo add-apt-repository "deb
  https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
- sudo apt-get update

  Reading package lists... Done
  E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt uma-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
  E: The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt trusty-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
- sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package postgresql-9.6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'postgresql-9.6' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: First,  you never replied in your previous post what you found. Second, [Apt Repo](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) shows that Trusty(14.04) is not supported in current repo. Third, why are you installing a version that is going EOL November 2021? Fourth, if you want old repo's see this [Archived repos](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/YBMtd6nRuXyU2zS4%40msg.df7cb.de), with the understanding these will not be getting any updates.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I try to build legacy project. It's work only with PostgreSQL 9.6. So I need exact PostgreSQL 9.6

Comment: So you have choice of installing from the archives with a package that will not be updated or building from source. I would make it a priority to migrate off 9.6 though.

Comment: Actually there is third choice. AFAICT([Mint versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history)), Mint 20.2 = Ubuntu 20.04(focal). So why not use the Focal repo? Then you could get updates until 9.6 goes EOL plus one more release.